# Getting the address of a contract before its deployed with brownie

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, javascript, hardhat, brownie

While working with the lens protocol contracts I saw that they were able to precompute the address of a contract using hardhat with the following code

```typescript
import { hexlify, keccak256, RLP } from 'ethers/lib/utils';

const followNFTNonce = hexlify(deployerNonce + 1);

const followNFTImplAddress =
    '0x' + keccak256(RLP.encode([deployer.address, followNFTNonce])).substr(26);
```

Is there a way to this with brownie?
I'm actually trying to refcator the lens code to be able to work with using brownie.
Help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!
If you want to get the next next contract address then keep on adding 1 to the nonce.

```
from brownie import Test, accounts
from web3 import Web3
import rlp

def main():
    deployer = accounts[0]
    deployer_address = deployer.address
    deployer_nonce = deployer.nonce

    print("Pre-computing Test contract Address..")
    test_contract_address = "0x" + Web3.keccak(rlp.encode([bytearray.fromhex(deployer_address[2:]), deployer_nonce])).hex()[-40:]
    print(test_contract_address)

    print("Deploying Test Contract")
    test_contract = Test.deploy({"from": deployer})
    print(test_contract.address)
```

There's also an in built method in brownie

```
account.get_deployment_address(nonce=whatever nonce you want)
```